# Next button will generate a new set of questions

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am trying to create an online quiz system using jsp and servlets.
When the user chooses the topic, it goes to the first question. After the user chooses their choice, and clicks on the next button, it is supposed to show a new set of questions and choices. I am not sure how to do that part. Here is my code so far:

Database:

```
public static MathQuestion getQuestionInfo(int questionNum)
    {
        MathQuestion math = new MathQuestion();
      //  int questionNum = 1;
        try
        {
            Connection conn = DBConnection.getConnection();

            String query = "SELECT * FROM MathQuestions where QuestionNumber = ?";
            PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
            stmt.setInt(1, questionNum);
        //    questionNum++;
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();

            while(rs.next())
            {
                math.setQuestionNum(rs.getInt("QuestionNumber"));
                math.setQuestion(rs.getString("Question"));

                String questionOptions = rs.getString("QuestionOptions");
                String[] splittedValues = null;
                for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                {
                   splittedValues = questionOptions.split(",");
                }
                math.setQuestionOptions(splittedValues);
                math.setCorrectAnswer("CorrectAnswer");
            }
        } 
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        return math;
    }
```

JSP

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Math</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Math Section</h1>

        <%
            String email = (String) session.getAttribute("email");
            int questionNum = (Integer) request.getAttribute("questionNum");
            MathQuestion math = new MathQuestion();

            if(email != null)
            {
                math = MathService.getQuestionInfo(questionNum);
            }

            String[] questionOptions = math.getQuestionOptions();
        %>

        <form name="MathForm" action="Math" method="post">
            Question <input type="text" value="<%=math.getQuestionNum()%>"> <br/>
            <input type="text" value="<%=math.getQuestion()%>"> <br/>

            <input type="radio" name="options" value="OptionA"><%=questionOptions[0]%> <br/> 
        <input type="radio" name="options" value="OptionB"><%=questionOptions[1]%> <br/>
            <input type="radio" name="options" value="OptionC"><%=questionOptions[2]%> <br/>    
            <input type="radio" name="options" value="OptionD"><%=questionOptions[3]%> <br/>

            <input type="button" name="Next" value="Next">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Servlet:

```
@WebServlet(name = "Math", urlPatterns =
{
    "/Math"
})
public class Math extends HttpServlet
{
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        if (SessionService.validateSession(request, response))
        {
            RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("math-page.jsp");
            request.setAttribute("questionNum", 1);
            dispatcher.forward(request, response);
        }
        else
        {
            RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("login-page.jsp");
            dispatcher.forward(request, response);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        for(int i = 2; i <= 10; i++)
        {
             RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("math-page.jsp");
             request.setAttribute("questionNum", i);
             dispatcher.forward(request, response);
        }

        String userChoice = request.getParameter("options");
    }
}
```